# Why does receiver for AlarmManager has no Intent Filter?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, intentfilter

I'm using the Alarm Manger in my project and i have this declaration in my Manifest. Everything is working Perfect and fine but I have this query in my mind that Why does the following

```
 <receiver android:name="wokerClasses.alarmReceiver"></receiver>
```

Declaration for the class that handles the receiver in its onReceive() has no intent-Filter? I want to understand that how does the system invoke and recognize that this specific receiver and Why no other sendBroadcast() invoke this receiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how does the system invoke and recognize that this specific receiver

You are creating a `PendingIntent`, using `getBroadcast()`, wrapping an `Intent` that identifies this `BroadcastReceiver`. That `Intent` is an explicit `Intent`, one that identifies the specific Java class of the component. The `PendingIntent` allows you to selectively grant other processes — such as the Android core process managing alarm events — to be able to send a broadcast to this receiver, even though that receiver is not exported.

> Why no other sendBroadcast() invoke this receiver.

That receiver is not exported; nothing else on the system can send it a broadcast, except:

- Your own code
- Anyone holding a `PendingIntent` that you give them

Comment: Can you please explain what's the point of having a receiver in Manifest while we have given an explicit intent to the System. Isn't that enough for the system to invoke this class?

Comment: @ShoaibAnwar: That is not how Google elected to do it, sorry.